# What is the "and" and "or" Operator in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, kotlin

We all know that in Java, we use the && operator for "and" and || operator or "or". But when it comes to Kotlin, this doesn't work. When I was trying out a simple program, I noticed that the && operator in Kotlin was behaving like the || operator in Java using IntelliJ, I have no idea why.

```
while(day!=1 && month != 1 && year!= 0) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I debugged the program, I saw that when day = 1, month = 8, year = 1947, it jumped out of the loop.

I modified the code and debugged again, this time it jumped out when day = 31, month = 1, year = 1947.

So what exactly is the "and" and "or" operator in Kotlin?

Comment: "when day = 1, month = 8, year = 1947, it jumped out of the loop."  false AND true AND true is **false**

Comment: As "we all know", that loop would also skip in Java when day = 1, because you wrote the loop to only iterate when `day != 1`. --- *"So what exactly is the "and" and "or" operator in Kotlin?"* They are the same as in Java, as you'd know if you bothered with a web search for [`Kotlin Operator`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kotlin+Operator), which would lead you right to the [**Kotlin documentation**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols): *"`&&`, `||`, `!` - logical 'and', 'or', 'not' operators"*.

Comment: People are not understanding the question. In Kotlin, we have `&&`, but we also have `and`. `&&` will perform a short circuit evaluation. `and` will not. What's the difference? Using `if (false && false)` as an example, the evaluation will stop at the first `false` because it already knows the outcome will be false. With `if (false and false`, both booleans will still be evaluated even though logically you could know the outcome is `false` from the first.

Comment: The difference between `&&` and `and` can be seen by running this application:

<code>
fun main() {
    if (x("A") and x("B")) {
        println("not called")
    }

    if (x("C") && x("D")) {
        println("not called")
    }
}

fun x(label: String): Boolean {
    println(label)
    return false
}
</code>

With `and` both A and B are written out as both sides are being evaluated, whereas the `&&` is shortcut and hence just write out C.

Answer (score 4):

There are two logical operators in Kotlin:

> || :true if either of the Boolean expression is true

and

> &&: true if all Boolean expressions are true

Note that, or and and are functions that support infix notations
.
Logical operators are used in control flow such as if expression, when expression, and loops.

For more information [here](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operators)

Comment: and operator and or operator do bitwise operations.

Answer (score 3):

To not jump out of the loop for day = 1, month = 8, year = 1947, the condition would have to be, for example:

```
while(day==1 && month != 1 && year!= 0) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Your initial condition says = If "day" isn't 1 and "month" isn't 1 and "year" isn't 0, only then continue. So it works as intended since parameter "day" is actually 1, and breaks out of the loop. You should read up on negation and logic gates, it will help you understand programming better, since logic gates have been exactly the same for around 100 years.